# How to create this effect?

Tags: wordpress

Hy

I have this theme.

http://venusdemo.com/wpopal/mix/fashion/

On the right side there are a few images that have an effect when we arrow above.

Thnaks in advance!
Does anyone know what kind of plug is used there or how were they created?

Comment: hi this was working css based on : hover display effect using bg image.

Comment: do you have a tutorial where you explain that? please

Comment: at that time no tutorial but this just some normal css just use firebug for see this.

when u have 20 repetition just send request  me at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/65335/wordpress-and-magento-developers

Answer (score 0):

```
.image-plus-1:hover:before, .wpb_single_image .wpb_wrapper > a:hover:before {
    opacity: 0.6;
    transform: scale(1) rotateY(0deg);
    visibility: visible;
}
.image-plus-1:before, .wpb_single_image .wpb_wrapper > a:before {
    background: url("../images/plus.png") no-repeat scroll center center / 60px 60px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: scale(0.5) rotateY(180deg);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```